# Does a potential hiring gives a motive to work harder?

Tags: internship, motivation

Over the last 6 months I'm doing my internship in a small office. I'm very satisfied. In the past they told me that business go well and they might need to hire a developer.

The last month I asked them if they have plans afterwards and they declined, they told me the opposite than first place.

After discussing this with a close friend, he told me that is a common practise in order to work harder? Is this true? Does this work as a motive?

Comment: Yes, lying to one's low-level employees is not an unheard of tactic. An while it's common for some internships to lead to gainful employee, it's also common that some internships are simply seen as free/cheap labor for the company.

Comment: Circumstances could have changed. If you're a software developer there's plenty of work. You won't have to look very hard.

Comment: Anyways still work hard improve your coding style and level

Comment: I think the questions is irrelevant. Since when does a 'negative' make you want to work harder? If they *don't* have a job opening, why would you want to work harder? If they *do* have a job opening they're lying to you - would you want to work for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell whether this was to make you work harder. It could be. It also could be the case they changed their minds. In general, companies don't want to do that because hiring you is less expensive.

Six months internship is long. You don't want to stay on internship forever.

My advice to you is to move forward, that is, look for full time jobs. Whatever past is past. You at least gained experience. Get reference letters from them and watch job ads. That's the thing you should do.

Comment: It could also be that they have jobs but chose not to offer one to the OP. Some people don't like to deal with hard conversations so they say something much less difficult. It is easier to say we are not hiring any interns at this time, than we don't like your work and are not interested in hiring you.

Comment: @HLGEM I must agree with you. I'm sure that was an excuse,I tend to believe that that was the true reason. I guess I can figure out if ask them for a reference letter?

Answer (score 5):

> After discussing this with a close friend, he told me that is a common
>   practise in order to work harder? Is this true? Does this work as a
>   motive?

When I've hired interns, I made it clear up front that there were no promises for future jobs.

That said, we often did hire promising interns into entry-level positions, once they finished their education. Word got around, and I know we became knows as a "place that might offer you a job".

I never expected or used that as a carrot to motivate the interns to work harder. They mostly worked hard anyway. And the ones who worked particularly hard got a great review from me at the end of their stint, and a promise to help them in any way I could once they graduated. I hired some, brought some with me to other companies, and gave great references for the ones I wasn't able to hire.

While I suspect it does happen, I don't know anyone personally who hires interns and lies about the possibility of a job in order to "motivate" them. I suspect word of that practice would get around and potential interns would be warned to stay away from companies who tried that. So it might work for a short while, but in the long run it probably wouldn't.

As far as I can tell, this isn't a common practice in my part of the world. In might be different elsewhere.